# How to print a formatted string with variable amount of key + values from a dictionary

Tags: python, string, formatting

Is it possible to print variable amount of key+values from a dictionary with str.format()? It would be nice if that would work in python2.

let's say I have a dictionary with some amount of keys+values, and I have to print keys+values of those keys which are stored in a list/tuple.

```
dict1 = { 'k1':'v1', 'k2':'v2', 'k3':'v3'}
to_print = ('k1', 'k2')
string = ''
for i in dict1:
    if i in to_print:
        string += "{" + i + "} " +  ', '

string = string.format(**dict1)
print(string[:-2])
```

The above code gives

```
v1 , v2
```

while I would like it to be formatted like this:

```
[k1] v1 , [k2] v2
```

**UPD:**

having challenges with that solution if a dictionaries are inside a list and i need to print key/values from one dictionary in one row, example:

```
list1  = [ { 'k1':'v1', 'k2':'v2', 'k3':'v3'} , { 'k1':'v4', 'k2':'v5', 'k3':'v6'} ] 
to_print = ('k1', 'k2')
for i in list1:
    for k,v in i.items():
        if k in to_print:
            elements = []
            elements.append(f"[{k}]: {v}")
            print(", ".join(elements))
[k1]: v1
[k2]: v2
[k1]: v4
[k2]: v5
```

while I need something like this:

```
[k1]: v1 , [k2]: v2
[k1]: v4 , [k2]: v5
```

Previously, I addressed that with the grouped function from the SO:

```
def grouped(iterable, n):
    "s -> (s0,s1,s2,...sn-1), (sn,sn+1,sn+2,...s2n-1), (s2n,s2n+1,s2n+2,...s3n-1), ..."
    return zip(*[iter(iterable)] * n)
```

any idea to make that better?

ok, figured that out:

````
elements = []
for i in list1:
    elements = []
    for k,v in i.items():
        if k in to_print:
            elements.append(f"[{k}]: {v}")
    print(", ".join(elements))```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dict1 = { 'k1':'v1', 'k2':'v2', 'k3':'v3'}
to_print = ('k1', 'k2')

elements = []
for key, val in dict1.items():
    if key in to_print:
        elements.append(f"[{key}]: {val}")

print(", ".join(elements))
```

Or could be done even shorter by using list comprehension:

```
print(", ".join([f"[{key}]: {val}" for key, val in dict1.items() if key in to_print]))
```

will yield:

```
[k1]: v1, [k2]: v2, [k3]: v3
```

Comment: The OP states `to_print = ('k1', 'k2')`. You should address that

Comment: @Sheldore ah yes! luckly it's a simple `if` fix.

Comment: You don’t need if statement. Just loop over the tuple and extract the corresponding value from the dictionary

Comment: @Sheldore that can work if the `dict1` data is precise, but if for example `k2` misses from the dict then you would have a `KeyError` raised. I usually prefer to assume that the input data is somewhat variable and could have duplicates, and keep the verification reference data just that... a verification reference, not a pivot of access.